# how to match two tables's column's value and get the result from perticular column's value in laravel relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, join, many-to-many, relationship

how to compaire two tables value and get the result of particular column value from both tables in laravel relationship method? I don't know how to do it with relationship,  at the same time I don't know whether it is based on many to many or one to many relationship. at the same time I have to do it with where condition.
here is my mormal query example for my requested code:
select teacher.teacher_name, subject. subject_name from teacher join subject on teacher.subject_token = subject.token where teacher.teacher_token = '1';

Comment: Please Explain more about your problems and attach a code for find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you, you want to get a teacher and his/hers subject?

```
Teacher::select(['id','name','subject_token'])->with('subject')->where('id', $id)->first()
```

Explanation: From the teacher's table take a teacher with id `$id` (id passed to the method) and take his id, name, and subject_token, with this get the subject that has the same token taken from the teacher's table. (Usually, instead of tokens you could use id)